# Scheduled powershell script invoke-expression not calling another script

Tags: powershell

I want to schedule a powershell script. It's okay but the powershell script contains an invoke-expression command and it's not calling another script.
Has anybody experienced a similar problem?

Comment: Can you provide some code for debug? Are you running it as an administrator?

Comment: @Syphirint running it with domain administrator credential. I tried it schedule with my credential without any success. But its working and call the other script when I start the scheduled script manually outside of the scheduler. My credential also has domain administrator right. Its not working only in scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, there are limitations of scheduled jobs. Try to move your code with Invoke-Command to separated script file and schedule Job as follows:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At '6 am'
$options = New-ScheduledJobOption -WakeToRun -RequireNetwork
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath .\ScriptWithInvokeCommand.ps1 -Name SampleJobName -Trigger $trigger -ScheduledJobOption $options -RunNow
```

You can also use Scheduled Task instead of Scheduled Job.

Comment: It would be great if I could use the invoke-expression or invoke-command inside the script. The other way is to implement the functions from the other script.